# Where do military aircraft carry flares?

Tags: military, fighter

Many sources on the internet say flares are carried in the fuselage, but do not specify the exact location of the compartment.

Does anybody know exactly where they are stored?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The location of the flare/chaff dispenser (FCD) depends on the aircraft type and even in case of the same aircraft, they can be located in different place, depending on the version and customer.

For example, the F-16 carries the FCD in its body fairing, as can be seen in the following image of Hellenic Air Force F-16 Demo Team “Zeus”.

[image: F-16 catridge]
<sup>Image from [theaviationist.com](http://theaviationist.com)</sup>

The following image shows a close view of FCD.

[image: F-16 flare]
<sup>Image from [f-16.net](http://f-16.net), credited to Capt. Lance</sup>

The following image shows an Israeli F-16B 'Nezt' having FCD between its ventral fins.

[image: F-16 FCD 1]
<sup>Image from [theaviationist.com](http://theaviationist.com)</sup>

---

Initially, most of the FCDs were retrofitted to the existing aircraft and were simply attached to them. However, most of the modern aircraft have FCD bays integrated into their fuselage. Still, some aircraft can carry extra flares/chaffs in their pylons (called PIDS (Pylon Integrated Dispenser System)), as shown below in an RDAF aircraft.

[image: PIDS]
<sup>Image from [f-16.net](http://f-16.net), credited to Erik Frikke</sup>

---

Also, most of the combat aircraft have the FCD in the bottom, while transport aircraft (and helicopters) have them on their sides.

Comment: The A-10 has it on the underside of the wingtip. See photo on your answer to [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22232/8730)