# Why do the winglets go down on some cessnas?

Tags: aerodynamics

I understand that the purpose of winglets is to decrease the wingtip vortexes to increase performance in climbs and cruising by redirecting the air over the wing. However on some old cessnas the winglets curve downwards. What is the reason for this?

Comment: A picture would be really helpful here, if you can find one.

Comment: @Pondlife The Cardinal II has wingtips that curve downwards, its difficult to get a good picture of it though.

Comment: http://s179.photobucket.com/user/Cardinal774/media/blog05cfo/wingtips.jpg.html is a good image to see a Cardinal II wingtip next to an older 177.

Comment: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/is-this-a-wing-tip-device-on-the-a-10-warthog has all the stuff you want in it.